# How to use Nokogiri to split content between successive h2 tags and wrap it under a chapter div

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to split a document into "chapters". A chapter starts at a h2 and includes all siblings up to but not including the next h2 tag.

I.e. given this

```
<div id="content">
  <h2>First</h2>
  <p>one</p>
  <h2>Second</h2>
  <p>two</p>
  <h2>Third</h2>
</div>
```

I want this

```
<div id="dad">
  <div class="chapter">
    <h2>First</h2>
    <p>one</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chapter">
    <h2>Second</h2>
    <p>two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chapter">
    <h2>Third</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Whilst I've used Nokogiri and xml to do some basic manipulation, I'm banging my heading wondering how to first group the nodes into chapter blocks and then wrap them in place with the chapter div.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should group your nodes by headers (include related subling nodes) and then transform them to output format.

Here is an idea of algorithm to group nodes:

```
array = [
  :header,
  :text,
  :text,
  :header,
  :text,
  :header,
  :text,
  :text,
]

groupped_array = array.reduce([]) do |res, item|
  res.tap do 
    res << [] if item == :header
    res.last << item
  end
end

p groupped_array
```

Result:

```
➜  ruby group_nodes.rb
[[:header, :text, :text], [:header, :text], [:header, :text, :text]]
```

I think you can add `nokogiri` here without big problems and transform result to your output format.